# mysql: specifiy user permissions

Tags: mysql, permissions

is there a way to limit GRANT SELECT user@db with something like a WHERE?
I have variable "PROJECTID" to assess certain records to a particular project. 
When user query all clients it should only show the clients from their projects. I do not want to change the interface for every user, so a select where statement will not help here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I fear, there is no such thing.

But you could create database views using a WHERE condition and then give permissions to those views to your users.